# Sound effect doesn't work, when buttons are clicked in the MouseArea

Tags: qt, qml

I am developing video game for casino slot machines.

So, I would like to write code so that a sound effect is played when the start button is pressed, but I have looked into methods and have not found a useful solution.
The slot rotates with `onClicked`, but I would like to add a sound effect as well. Do I need to add a separate method to avoid duplicating property bindings?
How should I write the code?

To avoid duplication of property bindings, I split them into `onClicked` and `onPressed`, but sound effect wasn't working.

Since `OnClicked` is already used as the method to start the game, we need to assign another method for sound effects.

Can someone please advise me on this?

```
 MouseArea {
      anchors.fill: parent
      onClicked: startClicked()
      onPressed:  { clickSound.play() }
    }


    // sound effect need add to MouseArea
         SoundEffect {
           id: clickSound
           source: "../assets/startSound.mp3"
         }
  }
```

Comment: *"Since onClicked is already used...we need to assign another method for sound effects"* -- Why can't you use the onClicked signal for both?

Comment: Did you try: `onClicked: { clickSound.play(); startClicked() }`?

Comment: @JarMan I tried it and it worked well.
I had perused the official guides and similar examples that Qt had provided, but was at a loss for clues as to information that would lead to application.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Great, I'll rewrite it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do more than one thing in a signal handler. You just need to put `{}` braces around the code. So change your onClicked handler to something like this:

```
onClicked: { clickSound.play(); startClicked() }
```

Or you can write it on multiple lines, like this:

```
onClicked: {
    clickSound.play()
    startClicked()
}
```